Automatically pull correct .NET runtime installer into my WiX installer?
I'm creating a WiX installer for a multi-process application where several of those processes use .NET 8. I need to include the .NET 8 desktop runtime installer because the end users cannot be expected to install the runtimes themselves. Is there a way to automatically download and package the single .NET runtime these processes are targeting without making every single executable self-contained?
I want to avoid the scenario where Visual Studio compiles against a later fix release of .NET than the version of .NET manually specified in the installer (say 8.0.8 vs 8.0.7). This causes unexpected "You must install .NET" popups in the middle of using the application.
